# Не могу заполнить таблицу в wpf?

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf

Как заполнить таблиц данными из бд. У меня  на данный момент получилось подключить базу данных. Но я не могу сделать чтобы заполнялись два столбца а не один.

```
public void FillGrid()
        {
            string MyConString =
            "SERVER=localhost;" +
            "DATABASE=hotel_op;" +
            "UID=root;" +
            "PASSWORD=mypassword;";

            string sql = "SELECT fio,bonus_card FROM client ";

            using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (MySqlCommand cmdSel = new MySqlCommand(sql, connection))
                {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmdSel);
                    da.Fill(dt);

                    clientGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
                    clientGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
                }
                connection.Close();
            }
        }



<DataGrid  x:Name="clientGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="0,0,-47,0">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding fio}" Header="Фамилия" Width="300"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding bonus}" Header="Бонусная карта" Width="140"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Как отображается.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
CREATE TABLE `client` (
  `fio` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `bonus_card` varchar(10) NOT NULL,)
```

прошу помочь с данной проблемой.

Comment: Измените в xaml с `bonus` на `bonus_card`

Comment: спасибо помогло @Kalmankantaja

Comment: Выглядит, как вопрос-опечатка. Если он решен, вы можете его удалить, тем более на скриншоте персональные данные, нарушение 152-ФЗ, если они настоящие.

Comment: @aepot можно ли считать персональные данные если имена придуманы?

Comment: @KaneJons если придуманы, то всё ок